# Create NHibernate Not Found Object for Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate

When you try to load an object with a bad ID, NHibernate returns a proxy that will throw `ObjectNotFoundExceptions` when you try to access any of its properties. I would like to test that my application handles those bad objects correctly. Currently, my tests work by mocking up the repositories to return the values that I want them to return. How do I create a not found object proxy that I can return from my mocked up repository?

Comment: As Micha stated - do as you currently do - make your repository mock return what you want it to return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mh,

I would simply mock an instance of your entity and set it up to throw `ObjectNotFoundExceptions` whenever you access a property.

And the mocked repository then simply returns that object for any query or get/load etc...

Comment: Yea that would work. I was hoping NHibernate had a helper method that would create one for me.

Comment: no not really, I mean if you mock the repository and everything, you will not use nhibernate for it anyways right?

Comment: True. In fact, the domain shouldn't even know about anything NHibernate anyway. It's just some technical debt that we have.